# using the group clause and aggregate functions to operate on row data

Tags: mysql, group-by, aggregate-functions, mysql-workbench

This is a snippet of table `tableA`:

```
station     code    persons    childLabour    DrinkingWater
staA         01     isaac      No              Yes
staB         05     Jane       Yes              Yes
staA         03     Jeff       No               No
staB         05     Saleh      No               Yes
staC         03     Henry      Yes              No
staA         01     Gera       No               No
staB         05     zoltan    Yes               Yes
staA         01     Allen      No               Yes
staC         04     Billy      No               Yes
staA         01     Jean       Yes              Yes
```

I am trying to formulate a query on that table that gives me a result as shown below:
**Explanation of the query result**:
Based on the station and code,calculate the number of persons whose `ChildLabour` value = `yes` and display result. Also calculate the number of persons whose `DrinkingWater` value is `Yes` and display result --for each station and corresponding code.

```
station       code     ChildLabour         DrinkingWater
staA           01       3                    4
staA           03       2                    1
staB           05       5                    10
```

So, my query thus far looks like this:

```
select distinct station,code, 
       (select count(persons) from `tableA` 
        where childLabour='Yes' 
        group by `station,code`) as `childLabour`
from `tableA` order by code `asc`;
```

but it generates the wrong result as shown below:
The query displays the same value(total of all persons whose childLabour value = Yes) in the entire column.

```
station code ChildLabour  DrinkingWater
staA     01     3           4
staA     03     3           4
staB     05     3           4
```

How do I get around this problem, I am sure its not a major problem!

Comment: I don't understand how the result set relates to the data set.

Comment: the result set: its the result i want to get to...

Answer (score 0):

Could try using `SUM` and only sum the values that are valid - equals yes:

```
SELECT station, code, SUM(IF(childLabour = 'Yes', 1, 0)), SUM(IF(DrinkingWater = 'Yes', 1, 0))
FROM tableA
GROUP BY station, code
```

Results:

```
staA    01  1   3
staA    03  0   0
staB    05  2   3
staC    03  1   0
staC    04  0   1
```

Explanation:

```
station     code    persons    childLabour    DrinkingWater
staA         01     isaac      No               Yes
staA         01     Gera       No               No
staA         01     Allen      No               Yes
staA         01     Jean       Yes              Yes
                                1               3
staA         03     Jeff       No               No
                                0               0
staB         05     Saleh      No               Yes
staB         05     Jane       Yes              Yes
staB         05     zoltan     Yes              Yes
                                2               3
staC         03     Henry      Yes              Nn
                                1               0
staC         04     Billy      No               Yes
                                0               1
```

These are the results and why i am getting them.

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9a269/3/0)

Comment: it doesnot work out, the query returns 0 in the ChildLabour column... but i need the sum or count of persons whose ChildLabour value = Yes!

Comment: Have another look, based on the data you provided, the output i`m getting and why - aren't you getting the same results on the same data you provide on the question ?

Comment: looking at the query:

Comment: SELECT station, code, SUM(IF(childLabour = 'Yes', 1, 0)) from main group by station,code;  the if returns a 1 if the childLabour is Yes. i need the count/sum function to calculate the number of persons with the condition set to true....for each grouped[station and code].

Comment: --> your query does not get me the correct result! #ThanksAnyway

Comment: Check out the sql fiddle i`ve added. Further more, i have no idea what is the correct result for you, since the solution works. Good luck.